# Azure Synapse Notebook Pull Data from Onprem?

Tags: azure-synapse

I'm trying to find documentation on this, but I don't see a definitive answer.  Is it possible to have a Synapse Notebook in Azure to connect directly to an On-Prem SQL Server to pull data into a dataframe using JDBC connections maybe?  Perhaps some other method?

Answer (score 1):

I spoke with a guy from Microsoft who works on the Synapse team, and he confirmed that as of right now, it's not possible to directly connect to your on-prem data sources directly through Synapse notebooks.

He suggested that the best way right now, is to bring your data into a Data Lake for example using pipelines, and then do your Synapse processing.

Comment: Yup, so far there are no options for this. At present alternative is we can use ADF with self-hosted integration runtime and move those to either azure sql db as tables (paas) or blob or data lake[ADLS] gen 2 as a file. then we can follow our synapse kind of activities.