# Fetching data from On-Premise Sql Server to Azure Synapse Notebook using Linked Service

Tags: azure, pyspark, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-analytics, azure-synapse-pipeline

I have made a self hosted integration runtime and created a linked service to sql server but having problem in fetching data in synapse notebook using pyspark code.

I want pyspark code for Fetching data from  On-Premise Sql Server to  Azure Synapse Notebook using Linked Service and IR
[image]
[image]

I have updated the code

[image]
Actually my server name is AKHAYASQL/SQL2019 and its in my local machine i am trying to connect it using self hosted IR

error message:
[image]

Comment: Could you please provide your approach and error if any got?

Comment: so first i have created self hosted IR and used that in copy activity. Its working fine .but when i am trying to access using synapse notebook using jdbc having problem .Is there any method to access directly on-premise SQL server to synapse notebook through self hosted IR and liked service

Comment: Could you please provide the error which you are getting?

Comment: Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o3914.load.
: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:315)

Comment: Could you please provide your sample code?

Comment: code-from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# Create a Spark session and configure the external JAR
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("SQLServer Connection") \
    .config("spark.jars", "synfs:/935/abc/mssql-jdbc-7.2.1.jre8.jar") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Configure linked service credentials
linked_service_name = "SqlServer1"
df = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", f"jdbc:sqlserver://;{linked_service_name}") \
    .option("dbtable", "[dbo].[employee]") \
    .load()

# Show the data
df.show()

# Stop the Spark session
spark.stop()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I tried to replicate the issue in my environment, with below code:

```
linked_service_name = "SqlServer1"
df = spark.read \
.format("jdbc") \
.option("url", f"jdbc:sqlserver://;{linked_service_name}") \ 
.option("dbtable", "dbo.student") \ 
.load()
df.show()
```

I got the same error:

[image]

I added driver to the code as mentioned below:

```
jdbcDriver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"       
linked_service_name = "SqlServer1"
df = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("driver", jdbcDriver)\
    .option("url", f"jdbc:sqlserver://;{linked_service_name}") \
    .option("dbtable", "dbo.student") \
    .load()
df.show()
```

I got below error:

[image]

As per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url?view=sql-server-ver16) Jdbc URl should be in below format:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://[serverName[\instanceName][:portNumber]][;property=value[;property=value]]
```

So, I connected to SQL server with above jdbc URL format with below code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("OnPremSQLFetch") \
    .getOrCreate()

query = "SELECT * FROM student"
data = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", f"jdbc:sqlserver://<serverName>:1433;databaseName=<dbName>") \
    .option("dbtable", f"({query})") \
    .option("user", "<userName>") \
    .option("password", "<password>") \
    .option("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver") \
    .load()

data.show()
```

It connected to on-premises sql server successfully.

[image]

If the on-premises data source is not publicly accessible, then copy the data from on-premises to Azure SQL database using [this](https://www.sqlshack.com/copy-data-from-on-premises-data-store-to-an-azure-data-store-using-azure-data-factory/) and retrieve data from Azure SQL database with mentioned code.

As per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/822578/how-to-connect-to-on-premise-sql-database-from-azu) it is not possible to connect on-premises sql server directly in synapse notebook. You can follow above procedures.

Comment: my server name is AKHAYASQL its in local sql server i want to connect that in azure notebook using a self hosted IR

Comment: Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/822578/how-to-connect-to-on-premise-sql-database-from-azu) once.

Comment: yes i checked that and also checked this one  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66584172/azure-synapse-notebook-pull-data-from-onprem  Is this not possible using self hosted IR and liked service in notebook directly

Comment: Yes as per above doc it is not possible

Comment: can you please update your answer so i can accept it